# How much space is available?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, git

The question says **Remove the entire `git` directory (it is not used in our tutorials). Now repeat the above calculation for disk space, but this time give the answer in blocks.** I successfully deleted the `git` directory but now I need to find the disk space in blocks I've done `df -k` and this came up:

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_lvm-root   6813696 4533956   2279740  67% /
devtmpfs                       234236       0    234236   0% /dev
tmpfs                          250168      84    250084   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          250168    4792    245376   2% /run
tmpfs                          250168       0    250168   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      508588  209632    298956  42% /boot
tmpfs                           50036      16     50020   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                           50036       0     50036   0% /run/user/0
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Hi, @Hunter12345 What is the path from which you deleted the `git` directory ?

Comment: Hey, @saisasanka I've deleted the git directory in `/usr/share/doc`

Answer (score 0):

Blocks traditionally had a size of 512 bytes (they had a strong correlation with disk sectors). You can tell `df` what block size, or unit, to use. From the [POSIX `df` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html):

> The format of the default output from df is unspecified, but all space figures are reported in 512-byte units, unless the -k option is specified.

Assuming your homework question assumes blocks are 512 bytes, just remove the `-k`. If `df` still uses 1k blocks, you might have the `BLOCKSIZE` variable set to `K`. Unset it with `unset BLOCKSIZE` and `set POSIXLY_CORRECT=yes`.

You can reduce the output to just include the relevant file system with

```
df .     # or maybe df /usr/share/doc
```

(assuming your current working directory is on the relevant file system).

Comment: Okay, I got this now. `Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_lvm-root   6813696 4534480   2279216  67% /`

Comment: But it's telling me to give the answer in blocks.

Comment: @Hunter12345 Does using `df --block-size=512` work? If all else fails, read the docs: `man df`.

Comment: @Hunter12345 To get the POSIX-mandated output (512 byte blocks) you need to set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT=yes` variable.

Comment: I think the question wants a `df -B`? to find the block but I don't know how to do that???

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Lets say you deleted the directory `git` from the path `/usr/share/doc`. Now run `df -k /` provided `usr/share/doc` is present on `/` partition.It might give you something like this:

```
    Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used   Available Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_lvm-root   6813696      4533956   2279740  67%    /
```

Here `6813696` is the total number of blocks available out of which `2279740` are free. Each block size is of 1024 bytes.

Now your homework answer would be `2279740` blocks.

You can always run `df -kh` to see the disk space utilization in human readable terms like `1GB` etc

But if you want block size to be `512` or somethng else, try this:

```
df --block-size=512 /

df --block-size=<your_block_size> <your_partition>
```

EDIT: To get the size in  Mega bytes try this:

`df -hm /`

The number under `Available` would be your answer.

Assuming its 2279740 blocks each of 1024 byte size are free, the answer in `Ms` would be `2226.30859375M`

Calculation : `2279740/1024` or

In bytes `2279740*1024` = 2334453760 bytes;

In KB: `2334453760/1024=2279740KB ;`

In MB `2279740/1024=2226.30859375M ;`

In G `2226.30859375/1024=2.174129486083984G`

For more options of `df` , try `man df` or `df --help`

Comment: Sorry it's telling me to give it in Ms (eg 112M)

Comment: @Hunter12345, added it to the answer.

Comment: @saisasnka Okay for some odd reason I'm getting a fail for that part I just don't even know what it's asking me. It says **Question 14: How much space is available?**
**Remove the entire git directory (it is not used in our tutorials). Now repeat the above calculation for disk space, but this time give the answer in blocks.**  Which the above answer says **In human readable form (eg 123M) how much disk space is available on the main filesystem?**

Comment: @Hunter12345 If you want the space in blocks, in the answer  its explained with `df -k` . If you want space in human readable format , its explained in the form of `df -h` or `df -hm` . If you want space in blocks , provided a block size , the answer is explained in the form of `df -B`.Now what are you getting fail for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TO_REMOVE="/usr/share/doc/git"
BASE_DIR=$(dirname $TO_REMOVE)

SIZE_BEFORE=$(df $BASE_DIR | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f 3 | tail -1)
rm -Rf $TO_REMOVE
SIZE_AFTER=$(df $BASE_DIR | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f 3 | tail -1)

echo $(($SIZE_BEFORE - $SIZE_AFTER))
```

`dirname` - strips the last component of path

`tr -s ' '` - squashes all spaces

`cut -d" " -f 3` - selects second column

`tail -1` - selects last row from column

Comment: Just saying, the OP doesn't want to delete `/usr/share/doc`